# Daily counters webpage

Tags: wolfram-cloud, web, databin, formpage

I'd like to deploy a website to display and increment counters that track daily activities.

Here's a minimal working example:

```
bin=CreateDatabin[]
CloudDeploy[FormPage[{"Pushups" -> {0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30}, 
                      "Water" -> {0, .5, 1, 2}}, 
     DatabinAdd[bin, {{"Pushups", Now, #Pushups}, {"Water", Now, #Water}}]; &], Permissions->"Public"]
```

[image]

I'm unsure how to customize the content of a `FormPage`. I would like to add this plot on the page below the submit button:

```
DateListPlot@Cases[Flatten[Normal@bin,1],{"Pushups",r__}:>{r}]
```

[image]

Along with a few tweaks for bonus points:

- replace drop-downs with buttons
- display the current daily counter values
- custom image banner at top of page
- custom fonts and colors

Comment: I think it'll depend on what the semantics are. You could probably use any of the cloud object mechanisms, but I think Databin is geared toward getting a historic record of one type of data structure. You essentially end up with a Dataset with timestamps. A counter sounds like more of a stateful thing, so probably not necessary to use Databin for that.

Comment: As for tracking daily activities, I used Mathematica to build an exercise tracker. It includes a webform to select the exercises I intend to do in the session, and then builds a form for recording the actual reps/weights for each selected exercise. I just used CloudPut. The exercise "types" are stored in one Association and the exercise "history" is stored in another Association.

Comment: Just re-reading this... I think it might be helpful to split this up into separate questions. I think designing a webform is one thread. Maybe you can explain what you've tried and what's challenging for you. The use of Databin versus just "plain" cloud objects might be a separate thread. I'm not sure what the question about showing dataset and plot on the same page is all about--maybe that's related to the webform--but that sounds like a separate thread. As it stands, I feel that this might just turn into an undirected discussion of how to design and implement a web app.

Comment: I updated the problem.

Comment: Not sure if Databin is best choice here or if there something more appropriate or modern

Comment: @lericr You could share your exercise tracker? FYI I will hopefully be using this bookmark on my phone, so it needs to be usable on mobile, hence the need for buttons and larger text.

Comment: I'm trying to put something together that will be intelligible...

Answer (score 3):

- **Replace drop-downs with buttons.** You can add your own controls for each form element. Not sure if SetterBar is what you want, and it seems to behave a bit strangely when it's deployed to the cloud, so you might have to experiment with other controls.

  ```
  exerciseForm = 
    FormPage[
      FormObject[
        {"Pushups" -> <|"Interpreter" -> {0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30}, "Control" -> SetterBar|>, 
         "Water" -> <|"Interpreter" -> {0, .5, 1, 2}, "Control" -> SetterBar|>}], 
        UpdateAndDisplayExerciseHistory]
  ```
- **Custom image banner at top of page.** You could probably use AppearanceRules for this.

  ```
  title = ImageResize[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Volubilis"}], 400];
  exerciseForm =
    FormPage[
      FormObject[
        {"Pushups" -> <|"Interpreter" -> {0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30}, "Control" -> SetterBar|>,
         "Water" -> <|"Interpreter" -> {0, .5, 1, 2}, "Control" -> SetterBar|>}],
      UpdateAndDisplayExerciseHistory,
      AppearanceRules -> <|"Title" -> title|>]
  ```
- **Custom fonts and colors**

  You can add your own labels. For example, the pushup form element specification might look like this:

  ```
  "Pushups" -> 
    <|"Interpreter" -> {0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30}, 
      "Control" -> SetterBar, 
      "Label" -> Style["Pushups", Blue]|>
  ```

I'm not sure what "display the current daily counter values" means.

Answer (score 2):

Let's stick with the Databin idea for now. It will give us the timestamp functionality for free. We can play with the form locally before deploying it.

- Create the databin

  ```
  exerciseDataBin = CreateDatabin["exercise"]
  ```
- Define a function to update the databin and produce the desired plot

  ```
  UpdateAndDisplayExerciseHistory =
    Function[
      data,
      DatabinAdd[
        exerciseDataBin, 
        <|"pushups" -> data["Pushups"], "water" -> data["Water"]|>]; 
      DateListPlot[TimeSeries[exerciseDataBin]]]
  ```

  This can probably be cleaned up, but I wanted to be explicit while testing things out.
- Now we can create the form page

  ```
  FormPage[
    FormObject[{"Pushups" -> {0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30}, "Water" -> {0, .5, 1, 2}}], 
    UpdateAndDisplayExerciseHistory]
  ```

Summary:

- The plot below the submit button is just whatever the result is of executing the submit function. You can play with the exact plotting functionality you want--I just chose something easy to test with. Aslo, there's probably a way to get it to display in the initial view before the first submit, but I didn't explore that yet.
- It's easier (in my opinion) to have explicit named functions that do the work so you can test them outside of the form context.
- If you use Databin, you don't need to do your own timestamping (like you were doing with Now).
- To test your databin, it's useful to apply Dataset, e.g. `Dataset[exerciseDataBin]`
- Once you're happy with your local testing, you can CloudDeploy it.

I think this gets you your basic functionality. I'll try to grab some time later to look at your bonus questions.